# Use network folder as eclipse workspace

Tags: eclipse, windows

I am trying to use a network folder (in windows) as my Eclipse workspace. I have looked online for solutions for a fix for networks folders with no positive results. I am unsure if this is possible to do, a quick fix, or if there is additional Eclipse settings that have to be altered.

**edit**
I have on one computer my eclipse workspace, and that folder is shared with my HomeGroup (windows file sharing). It is also shared as a network folder.

I need to access these files on another computer without having to copy and paste the source to my secondary pc.

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: What is the problem? Eclipse shouldn't be able to tell the difference between a network folder and a normal folder.

Comment: my apologies, i will edit the question with more specificaitons

Comment: @foo This shouldn't also be a problem, just make sure that the eclipse on the first pc is closed, before you start eclipse on the second.

Comment: If you really want two eclipse instances you should consider using git, bazaar, mercurial or svn.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind, i wish it was that simple. i have double checked that my IDE was closed, still no positive results.

Comment: @foo What is the exact problem? What happens wenn you try to open the second eclipse?

Comment: @Absurd-Mind the network folder is not available for selection when selecting Eclipse's workspace

Comment: @foo Then i would say your network folder is not mounted correctly

Comment: @Absurd-Mind, could you please refer me to an example on mounting folders, that would be of great help (if that is the solution)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it would not allow me to access the network folder was because the folder remained in its 'read only'state. After restarting my computer, it allowed me to change the folder properties to `Read/Write` allowing me to access the folder as an Eclipse workspace.